# How can I sectionwise scale a nurb surface

Tags: matlab, nurbs

I'm trying to find a way to interpolate between sections of a wing.I have n aerofoil sections with n installation angles. However I have some more code which gives m scale fators for the wing geometry, where m>n.
I've constrcted a surface nurb with the wing sections and twist, and now need a way to scale it at spanwise sectional locations. I am aware I could convert back into cartesian points and scale thes but am loathe to do this now that I have a surface. Has anyone got an idea how I could go about this.
I am using the [nurbstoolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26390-nurbs-toolbox-by-d-m-spink) and [nrbloft](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14479-nrbloft)
Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks